# Is it possible to get a work permit/visa while staying as a tourist in Kosovo?

Tags: working-visas

I'm from istanbul,Turkey and I want out. I don't think I can live here anymore and would like to move to Prizren,Kosovo. Why Prizren? Because people there speak Turkish, its quiet and its affordable for me. Anyway, I want to live a simpler life and don't want to be a bigshot in companies. Just want to be some chef or waiter in a restaurant. It seems possible that they hire a Turkish in Prizren. 
Kosovo gives 90 day stay permit without a visa.

So my question is:

If I get an invitation from an agency and enter the country as a tourist (on paper) and look for a job, then find a job, Will this job get me a work permit? Is it legal to do this?

the other alternative is to get an invitation from a business before moving to Kosovo, but how do I get an invitation from a restaurant owner in Prizren right now? seems very hard.

my source : http://www.moveoneinc.com/country-profiles/kosovo/immigration-to-kosovo/

Comment: Please do not edit questions or answers to delete the content.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's ok to go there as a tourist, look for a job and ask the autorities to extend your stay. From [rks-gov.net](http://www.rks-gov.net/en-US/Qytetaret/InfoPerTeTuajt/Pages/LejeteQendrimitDhePunes.aspx):

> Normally, visitors that are allowed entry into Kosovo are permitted to
>   stay up to 90 days. **The persons willing to extend their stay for more
>   than 90 days should appear at the Foreigner Registration Office**, which
>   is located in the Headquarters building at Luan Haradinaj Street in
>   Prishtina.
>
> The stay permit for foreigners in Kosovo – For a longer stay in Kosovo
>   the foreigners should apply at the Foreigner Registration Office for a
>   stay permit in Kosovo. **A temporary stay permit may be issued to
>   foreigners for these reasons**:
>
> - Tourism and entertainment
> - **Employment and business**
> - Studying in one of the educational institutions in Kosovo
> - Family union with a permanent resident of Kosovo
> - Family union with a member of diplomatic body in Kosovo
> - Marriage with a permanent resident of Kosovo
>
> A stay permit may be extended, if the reasons the permit was issued
>   have not changed and if the application for this permit was justified
>   with required documents.